# Can I buy a one way ticket to Jamaica

Tags: tickets, jamaica

I got married to a Jamaican this year. Now I'm about to go back to apply for residency or citizenship. I know the process is going to take three to six months. Is it compulsory that I buy a return ticket right away?

Comment: What's your citizenship currently, and where would you be flying from?

Comment: Without a Visa yet, you will need a return ticket and have 90 days to stay maximum. You can pay money back in your host country for longer stays prearranged.